# In neural networks, is applying dropout the same as zeroing random neurons?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, dropout

Is applying dropout equivalent to zeroing output of random neurons in each mini-batch iteration and leaving rest of forward and backward steps in back-propagation unchanged? I'm implementing network from scratch in `numpy`.

Comment: Yes, although just to be super-duper-extra precise, *bernoulli* dropout is the same as zeroing-out random neurons (some people use other kinds of randomness and call it things like Gaussian dropout; see e.g. https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/gaussian_dropout/)

Comment: @Qbik please see edits to my reply below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed. To be precise, the dropout operation will randomly zero some of the input tensor elements with probability $p$, **and furthermore**  the rest of the non-dropped out outputs are scaled by a factor of $\frac{1}{1-p}$ during training.

For example, see how elements of each tensor in the input (top tensor in output) are zeroed in the output tensor (bottom tensor in output) using pytorch.

```py
m = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
input = torch.randn(3, 4)
output = m(input)

print(input, '\n', output)

>>> tensor([[-0.9698, -0.9397,  1.0711, -1.4557],
>>>        [-0.0249, -0.9614, -0.7848, -0.8345],
>>>        [ 0.9420,  0.6565,  0.4437, -0.2312]]) 
>>> tensor([[-0.0000, -0.0000,  2.1423, -0.0000],
>>>        [-0.0000, -0.0000, -1.5695, -1.6690],
>>>        [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, -0.0000]])
```

EDIT: please note the post has been updated to reflect Todd Sewell's addition in the comments.

Comment: Note that non-dropped out elements are scaled by 1/(1-p) to compensate for the shift in average magnitude, so it's not _just_ zeroing out some elements.

Comment: That is very true, I omitted that info from the original pytorch docs for simplicity however in that way makes the post only half correct. Amended now to reflect your point.